# How to combine multiple row data in a column in select query oracle?

Tags: oracle, join

For example:- I have 3 tables .

**student** :

```
student_id | name | rollNo | class 
         1 |  a1  | 12     | 5
         2 |  b1  | 11     | 5
```

**address**: there can be multiple address for a user

```
street  | district| country |student_id
  gali1 | nanit   | india | 1
  gali2 | nanital | india | 1
```

**Books** : There can be muliple book for the user

```
       book   | book_id |student_id
      history | 111      | 1
      Science | 112    | 1
```

This is example . I want data to be like this in output .
If i select for student_id 1. Then this would be result

```
student_id | name | rollNo | class | addresslist   | booklist
          1 |  a1  | 12     |  5    | some sort of |  some sort of
                                    |  list which  |  list which
                                    |  contain both|  contain both
                                    |  the address |  the book detail
                                    |  of user     |  of user
```

I am using 12.1 which does not support json for now it is in 12.2 .

addresslist can be like this you can create list as you want but it should have all this data.

```
[{street:"gali1","distict":"nanital","country":"india","student_id":1},{"street":"gali2","distict":"nanital","country":"india","student_id":1}]
```

same for booklist

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Group by `student_id` and use `listagg` and string concatenation `||` to get the string of addresses and books.

Comment: If it's just about a reporting query, then after you create it, or put it in a view, you can select the addresses with the `listagg()` built-in function, smth like this `select s.student_id, s.name, s.rollno, s.class
, listagg(a.country || ' ' || a.district || ' ' || a.street) within group (order by a.country) as addresslist
, listagg(b.book_id || ' ' || b.book) within group (order by a.book_id) as booklist
from student s , address a, books b
where s.student_id = a.student_id 
  and s.student_id = b.student_id;` group by could be added as well.

Comment: @g00dy This gives error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: we have to add group by at the end too. `group by s.student_id, s.name, s.rollno, s.class;`

Comment: A common mistake is missing fields in the last group by clause. Every select field should be also in the group by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
WITH json_addresses ( address, student_id ) AS (
  SELECT '[' ||
         LISTAGG(
           '{"street":"' || street || '",'
             || '"district":" || district || '",'
             || '"country":" || country|| '"}',
           ','
         ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY country, district, street )
         || ']',
         student_id
  FROM   address
  GROUP BY student_id
),
json_books ( book, student_id ) AS (
  SELECT '[' ||
         LISTAGG(
           '{"book_id":"' || book_id || '",'
             || '"book":" || book || '"}',
           ','
         ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY book, book_id )
         || ']',
         student_id
  FROM   book
  GROUP BY student_id
)
SELECT s.*, a.address, b.book
FROM   student s
       INNER JOIN json_addresses a
       ON ( s.student_id = a.student_id )
       INNER JOIN json_books b
       ON ( s.student_id = b.student_id );
```

Comment: Can be not do it by single select query ?

Comment: @Himanshusharma It is done with a single query. If you mean "can I join the tables and then use `LISTAGG`"? Not if you do not want duplicates in your JSON.

Comment: that would be help for me and for all who are searching solution.

Comment: I have find the solution for single query too. will add